# Is it possible to use <iframe> to point to an .aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to use an `<iframe>` to point to an `.aspx` file, but when I load it I keep getting an **empty frame**, no matter what is in the target `.aspx` nothing gets displayed. Here the html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        This is the principal page</div>
        <iframe id="myIframe" src="SimpleTarget.aspx" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I tried it pointing to an html and it was succesfully rendered in the browser showing the html content. Here the html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        This is the principal page</div>
        <iframe id="myIframe" src="HTMLPage1.htm" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So my question is, am I missing something when defining the `iframe` or is completely impossible to point to an `.aspx` with an `iframe`?

In case it is impossible, is there another way to show aspx pages within another html page?

Comment: Yes, it's possible . . . . Have you first tried to see if your .aspx page loads properly outside the iFrame?

Comment: What you have should work assuming your aspx page works properly. Post the aspx page code.

Comment: What are the full paths of the pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work with SimpleTarget.aspx just make sure that the relative path is correct and the page is loaded when you hit it with the browser ...

Answer (score 3):

Is this bit a typo? if not it could be your problem

```
src="SimpleTarget.aspx"height="100%"
```

should be

```
src="SimpleTarget.aspx" height="100%"
```

This is also a typo (but would not break your rendering.

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="HTMLPage1.htm" 100%" width="100%">
```

should be

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="HTMLPage1.htm" height="100%" width="100%">
```

Comment: oh man im sorry it was a copy paste mistake you are right.. Look the original post it is corrected

Comment: are you still having the same issue with the corrected syntax?  If so, have you loaded the ASPX page on it's own to make sure it loads?  If it does not load. Why?

Answer (score 1):

A request for an .aspx page is no different from a request for an HTML file.  Either your asp page is not rendering properly (possibly a server error?) or else your iframe is not pointing to it correctly.

I do notice that you have a badly formatted src tag for the .aspx page..

```
src="SimpleTarget.aspx"height="100%"
```

should be

```
src="SimpleTarget.aspx" height="100%"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the following in a Global.asax file stopped iframes opening aspx pages:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
}
```

Used to stop cross site scripting but also breaks internal iframes when using aspx pages; removing this "fixed" the problem for me.

Comment: +1. To read more about the header `X-Frame-Options`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

Answer (score 0):

In firefox you can right click in th iframe and get an iframe menu and choose to open the frame in a new tab - this will confirm the actual url being used by the browser for the iframe and as others have stated allow you to ensure the aspx page does render correctly.