# Accessing SSRS report through ASP.NET and then link with .NET Core Iframe is not working

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, iframe, reporting-services

I have an ASP.NET web application without user authentication that contains a report viewer that accesses reports from the SSRS link. It's working perfectly

Now I need to use the asp.net page link in my .NET Core application in iFrame Tag. It is visible until the report loading view then it shows an error:

> ASP.NET session has expired or could not be found

Comment: Probably not the issue, but [maybe a setting in Global.asax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9600389/3585500).